# excel formula, filename, cell reference, countif, date

Tags: excel

I am using this excel formula

```
=COUNTIFS(FILENAME_100720.csv!$AH$1:$AH$999999, "*"&A33&"*")
```

I am using this formula in multiple cells and would like use cell E5=100720 in the formula.
How can I change the formula so that the filename references the cell E5=100720?

Comment: `INDIRECT`. Note that the target file needs to be open.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this works.

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("FILENAME_"&E5&".csv!$AH$1:$AH$999999"), "*"&A33&"*")
```